# How to get the middle word using Substring via Charindex of Second Position?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically what I am trying to do is that I want to get the middle word, using the second occurrence of the same character **(on this case, dash "-")**.

This is the sample input:

```
declare @word nvarchar(max)
set @word = 'Technical Materials - Conversion - Team Dashboard'
```

There are three parts on this sentence, and they are divided by '-' dash line.

The **first part** is 'Technical Materials' which I am able to get using:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@word, 0, CHARINDEX('-', @word, 0))))
```

The **last set** was 'Team Dashboard' which I am able to get using:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(@word) - LEN(REPLACE(@word, '-', '')) = 1
            THEN NULL
        ELSE
            RIGHT(@word,CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(@word))-1)
        END
```

The problem was, I am having a hard time getting the middle words which is 'Conversion' in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the format **is fixed**, you can use [`PARSENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql) to achieve your expectation:

```
DECLARE @Word AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Technical Materials - Conversion - Team Dashboard'
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(@Word, '-', '.'), 2)
```

if you want to trim the extra spaces, then:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(PARSENAME(REPLACE(@Word, '-', '.'), 2)))
```

Comment: What do you mean if the format is fixed? I mean what format that this code will not work?

Comment: he means if you always have 2 '-' and not '.' in the value

Comment: I meant the two dashes here. The query need to change if it has less/more than 2 dashes

Comment: @GuidoG This query will work if you have two dots instead of two dashes or, one dash with one dot.

Comment: @Arulkumar yes I know, but it will not work if there are already a few dots in the value somewhere, right ?

Comment: for example 'Tech. Materials - Conversion - Team Dashb.'

Comment: be aware that if the text contains period or there are more than 3 '-' this will fail

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(@word,
              CHARINDEX('-', @word) + 2,
              CHARINDEX('-', @word, CHARINDEX('-', @word) + 1) -
                  CHARINDEX('-', @word) - 3)
FROM yourTable
```

The general strategy here is to use `SUBSTRING()`, which requires the starting and ending positions of the middle string in question.  We can use `CHARINDEX` to find both the first and second dash in the string.  From this, we can compute the positions of the middle substring we want.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Comment: Same with me. Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: Sorry guys, I switched the order of parameters being passed to `CHARINDEX`.  It seems to be working now.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This will find the text between the first 2 occurrences  of '-'

```
DECLARE @word nvarchar(max)
SET @word = 'Technical Materials - Conversion - Team Dashboard'

SELECT SUBSTRING(x, 0, charindex('-', x))
FROM (values(stuff(@word, 1, charindex('-', @word), ''))) x(x)
```

This will find the middle element. In case of an even number of elements it will pick the first of the 2 middle elements

```
DECLARE @word nvarchar(max)
SET @word = 'Technical Materials - Conversion - Team Dashboard'

;WITH CTE(txt, rn, cnt) as
(
  SELECT
    t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)'),
    row_number() over (order by (select 1)), count(*) over()
  FROM (
        SELECT x = CAST('<t>' + 
          REPLACE(@word, ' - ', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
) a
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/t') t(c)
)
SELECT txt
FROM CTE
WHERE (cnt+1) / 2 = rn
```